# how to work with .net array?

Tags: .net, arrays, f#

I read about that when deal with array we should use like `myArray.[i]`, however, from my experience `myArray[i]` compiles too.

However, when I want to write to an array in .Net (so it is mutable), this gives an error  `let myArray.[i] = 3` but `let myArray[i] =3` works.

What is the best practice to deal with such thing?

Also, should I use `Array.get` or use `.[]`?

How do I set value to a jagged array e.g. `let myArray.[i].[j] = 5`

Comment: `let setJagged (a: 'T[][]) (i: int) (j: int) (v: 'T) = a.[i].[j] <- v` and `let set2D (a: 'T[,]) (i: int) (j: int) (v: 'T) = a.[i,j] <- v`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1) If you want to assign a value to an array cell, use the assignment operator `<-`:

```
myArray.[i] <- 3
```

2) `let myArray[i] = 3` compiles because the compiler understands it as `myArray` function with a list as its argument and returns `3`. If you read the warning and the type signature, you will see you're doing it wrong.

3) `Array.get` is [a single call to `.[]`](https://github.com/fsharp/fsharp/blob/master/src/fsharp/FSharp.Core/array.fs#L655). `Array.get` is convenient in some cases for function composition and avoiding type annotation. For example you have

```
let mapFirst arrs = Array.map (fun arr -> Array.get arr 0) arrs
```

vs.

```
let mapFirst arrs = Array.map (fun (arr: _ []) -> arr.[0]) arrs
```

Answer (score 4):

Neither of your approaches is correct.  Assuming that you have some definitions like

```
let myArray = [| 1; 7; 15 |]
let i = 2
```

what you actually want is something like this:

```
myArray.[i] <- 3
```

When you write

```
let myArray[i] = 3
```

you are actually defining a **function** myArray, which takes an integer list and returns an integer.  This is not what you want at all.

Answer (score 2):

The problem here is that you're trying to embed an array assignment inside of a let expression. The expression `let myArray[3] = 2` is *not* an assignment into an array. Rather, it's a function definition. See what happens in fsi:

```
let myArray[i] = 3;;
val myArray : int list -> int
```

(There's actually a warning in there as well). Formatting it differently also reveals this fact: `let myArray [3] = 2`.

As the others have pointed out, `.[]` is for array access, and to assign to an array, you use `myArray.[i] <- 3` (*not* inside a let expression).